# Iron Router, Publish and Subscribe

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, iron-router

So I have a simple view that shows a Project and the Stories in that project. In iron router I'm calling this the projectShow route:

```
@route 'projectShow', {   
  path: '/projects/:_id', 
  template: 'projectsShow'
}
```

My template is

```
<template name="projectsShow">
  <div class="row">         
    I'm a project            
    {{name}}
    <a href="#" id="add-story">New Story</a>
    {{#each stories}}
      Title: {{title}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

So the part that's tripping me up is correctly selecting the data from the server and serving it to the client. What I've tried is publishing like so:

```
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.publish "projectAndStories", (id) ->
    [Projects.findOne({_id: id}), Stories.find({projectId: id})]
```

What's unclear to me is where and how to correctly subscribe to this in the router / client-side, as well as setting a session variable so I can reference the current project when adding new stories

I tried:

```
# in route
waitOn: ->
  Meteor.subscribe('projectAndStories', @params._id)
  Session.set('projectId', @params._id)

# template js file
  Template.projectShow.project = Projects.findOne({_id: Session.get('projectId')})
  Template.projectShow.stories = Stories.find({projectId: Session.get('projectId')})
```

However, this does not appaer to be making it into the template. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you return `Session.set('projectId', @params._id)` in waitOn closure.

You should return **Meteor.subscribe**. Simply swap the lines.

---

There were more issues than above one, so I decided to recreate your project in js and it works. 
Please take look on repository:
https://github.com/parhelium/stackoverflow-iron-pub-sub

Issues I noticed:

```
// Template.projectShow:   
{{name}} -> {{project.name}}

// waitOn closure should return:
Meteor.subscribe('projectAndStories', @params._id)
```

Issue I faced during creating your project:

```
// assign p to projectId, NOT p._id 
var p = Projects.insert({
    name: "Project #"+i,
});
Stories.insert({
    title: "Story #"+j,
    projectId:p
});

// check if data in mongo is correct, projectId was null in my case...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead of `waitOn`

```
before: ->
    this.subscribe("projectAndStories",@params.id).wait();
    Session.set('projectId', @params._id)
```

Make sure you've set your `loadingTemplate`. Which will be shown until the subscription is complete.